# Error while running MT4J

Tags: java, mt4j

Everytime I run an example files from the MT4J package. It will not run and display me his error.

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Umar\Downloads\MT4j\jogl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:189)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:80)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:103)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$200(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$1.run(NativeLibLoader.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadCore(NativeLibLoader.java:109)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.WindowsGLDrawableFactory.<clinit>(WindowsGLDrawableFactory.java:60)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.getFactory(GLDrawableFactory.java:106)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.allocate(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:209)
    at processing.core.PGraphics3D.setSize(PGraphics3D.java:316)
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:1165)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:999)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:959)
    at org.mt4j.MTApplication.setup(MTApplication.java:329)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1400)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1328)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't correctly pointed to the libraries with your IDE.

if you are using eclipse: 
From within your MT4j project, along the top bar, click Project -> Properties
Does the side choose Java Build Path and go to the tab Libraries.

make sure the mt4j libraries that come as .jar files are includes in there. In particular the jogl.jar found in mt4j-desktop/lib/jogl and the jogl-natives-xxx for operating system specific.