# Error while running advanced MTShell in MT4J

Tags: java, eclipse, mt4j

I have problem running MT4J examples. I try running he advance MTShell and I get the following errors.

Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Umar\Downloads\mt4j-desktop\jogl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:189)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:80)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:103)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$200(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$1.run(NativeLibLoader.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadCore(NativeLibLoader.java:109)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.WindowsGLDrawableFactory.(WindowsGLDrawableFactory.java:60)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.getFactory(GLDrawableFactory.java:106)
    at org.mt4j.util.opengl.CustomPGraphicsOpenGL.allocate(CustomPGraphicsOpenGL.java:73)
    at processing.core.PGraphics3D.setSize(PGraphics3D.java:326)
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:1325)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1146)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1106)
    at org.mt4j.MTApplication.setup(MTApplication.java:210)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1580)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1502)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Answer (score 0):

Your libraries aren't correctly linked. I answered this exact question in another post:

[Error while running MT4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716430/error-while-running-mt4j/18007082#18007082)